# GKE Cluster Audit

Tags: security, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, audit

1. What are the points to be reviewed while auditing a GKE cluster?
   We have a production cluster and I would like to what all points need to be reviewed while auditing my GKE cluster. What needs to be configured/removed for better security and HA.

Comment: Perhaps this is a start https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/gke-cis-benchmarks-deliver-security-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad topic.

Short answer(Main points):

- Apply Least privilege principle for IAM entities and RBAC entities
- Enable binary authorizarion
- Limit privileges on Containers
- Enable image scanner
- Use the Secret Manager
- Create private clusters when possible
- Spread your work nodes between AZs

But I strongly recommend you verify Google official docs:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/security-overview#node_upgrades

See ya